# Displaying an Error when clicking a pay with apple button

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I am implementing  apply pay with stripe. When I clicked  a button  it doesn't show the proceed to pay page and it shows an error like

```
"Failed to present in-app payment interface: Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=-1" 
Cannot Present Remote Interface of type: PDRemoteInterfaceTypeInAppPayment
```

and Connection to remote alert view service failed.
How to solve that error.what's that meaning of the error     PassbookUiService error

[image]

Comment: The error in the file says its a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, which means you are trying to work with a variable which doesn't exists, or rather you are trying to access something in a memory address which doesn't exists in the time of accessing it.

Comment: How to solve that one

Comment: create an exception breakpoint in xcode and run it. The code where this exception is happening will be highlighted while you encounter the error

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: NO. It displaying the same error